# How to install Canon Maxify MB2320

Tags: printing, canon

Greetings and thank you in advance for your assistance.

Although new to Ubuntu, I worked on Unix systems for years, years ago and slowly things are coming back and looking familiar. All the same would say I am green still.

Recently purchased a Canon Maxify MB2320 printer, with the thought based on research it would be easy to install on Ubuntu - well not completely.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) have attempted to install the printer via wifi and direct connect (USB) with essentially the same results.  When I go to install the printer (with either connection type), the system sees the printer, but (recommends) installing it as a generic - which I have tried unsuccessfully - when attempting a test print as a generic printer received a CUPS error that the format is not supported.

Stepping beyond that selected the printer type (Canon) and MP230 as the type.  With these parameters, I can see the test print move through the print queue, appearing to be working correctly, however nothing prints.

Am sure more information may be required in resolving this issue and I apologize in advance for not including any and all necessary information.  Not sure exactly what is required, but please let me know and I will provide such information as I am able.

Again, thank you in advance.

~Respect

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to [Canon USA's website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/small-office-home-office-printers/mb2320).
2. At top right, click on the red colored `Drivers and Downloads`.
3. Under `Enter a Model`, type `Maxify MB2320`.
4. Select `Drivers`.
5. Select `IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)`
6. Wait for the download to finish.
7. Select `ScanGear MP Ver. 3.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)`.
8. Wait for the download to finish.
9. Highlight the downloaded file. Right click and extract in `Downloads`.
10. In a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run the following commands:

    ```
    cd ~/Downloads
    ./scangearmp2-3.00-1-deb
    ```
11. If questions are asked, answer them.
12. Do the same with the printer file.

Comment: Thank you, successfully downloaded the drivers and extracted them.  Ran into a problem when installing scangear - driver not found in location - need to edit the install.sh file and see what is going on.  When installing the print driver, received the error - ./install.sh: 27: ./install.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: I reached the limit of my experience with installing the MB2320 drivers in my first post, this topic. Maybe use sudo ./ and see if that is better. ALSO, once installed after you print or scan a few pages, do: cd /var/tmp and then do ls cnij* and then if there is a list of cnij* do this, within /var/tmp directory sudo rm cnij* and then do ls cnij* to see that the cnij* are all gone. They fill up /var/tmp quickly and cause the OS to think that / is full. Thanks to Olathe for the code editing.

Comment: This worked for me on 17.04 by extracting the *deb.tar.gz files and running `sudo ./cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb/install.sh`